# What are the mechanisms that cause bananas to ripen? How is or isn't it related to the banana peel ripening?

Tags: food, fruit

So recently our commercial kitchen got some bunches of bananas with a curious feature. On the inside they were firm and delicious (no jokes, please), on the outside they looked incredibly sickly. Specifically, they had this grey/green/brownish yellow with lots of black spots, some of them with *depth*.

Situational details: these are Cavendish bananas, and a weekend of ripening in the open air did nothing for them.

This got us curious about the mechanisms of banana ripening - it's clearly not as closely related to how good the banana is to eat as we previously thought! Can someone explain it more?

Comment: Check the situational details I just added.

Comment: Ah, not Canarian then. In any case, this question is not really on topic here as it has nothing to do with the underlying biology. I would suggest,however, that you have one half-opened banana, allowing your customers to see that the inside is fine despite the blemishes. If you place the peeled banana next to the others, your customers should see that they should never judge a banana from its peel!

Comment: I couldn't find a cooking/culinary/restaurant .SE, so I posted it here as the _most_ relevant field.

Comment: Yes, indeed, and you took pains to politely acknowledge the possibility of its not being on topic. My last comment was not a complaint. You could try your luck over at [cooking.SE](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: If you flag your post, you can ask a mod to migrate it for you.

Comment: Actually, I'm going to do it manually, so I can split the topic into the mechanics of it (here) and what other people do to reduce the problem (cooking.SE).

Comment: You can get the basic mechanistic details on wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ripening - for example fruits are shipped before ripe and then gassed with ethylene. This is a chemical important in apoptosis and ripening processes, it is given off by ripe/damaged fruits. So, what you can do is pick fruit before it is ripe, store it in a cool dark place then when you want to ripen put the desired amount in a paper bag with a few slices of apple.

Comment: @rsegal (can I recommend you change this question completely to ask "what are the mechanisms which cause fruit to ripen?" or something along those lines)

Comment: I'm closing this as [it has been answered on Seasoned Advice](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/30703/how-do-banana-peels-reflect-its-ripening-state-can-we-influence-that-in-our-kit)